# Getting error Class 'HTML' not found when trying to call image in place of title

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5

I am using this code to get logo image in place of title text

```
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}
```

but getting an error. I also tried to `Illuminate\Html\HtmlServiceProvider::class`, and

`'Form' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class, 'Html' => Illuminate\Html\FormFacade::class`

in app.php file but still error exists. I need help to resolve this.

Comment: You used providers only after you installing `composer require laravelcollective/html` ?

Comment: yes i did. Let me know next step

Comment: Change HTML to Html

Comment: Thanks it worked now

Comment: Great. Please accept it as answer... :)

Comment: post this in answer :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Change HTML to Html
So

```
{{ HTML::image('images/logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}
```

becomes

```
{{ Html::image('images/logo.png', 'alt text', array('class' => 'css-class')) }}
```